# Android | Send data from one device to other device(s) without Wifi

Tags: android, client, host

I would like to program an app in which a mobile phone can choose the host and all others can connect as clients to the host. For example, if client A is sending data, the host should receive it and send a response to client A and client B, and so on. Is there any way to do this without Wifi?

Best regards
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

How about Mobile data? Just do the same but let them type client's ip address. ..

Comment: I want to completely renounce Internet use.

Comment: Well in that case I think only Bluetooth left. . Take a look at this : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#ConnectingDevices